# Unifying DNS endpoint from inside and outside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I have a VPC which has an autoscaling group. I want to be able to access this autoscaling group both from other servers in the VPC and externally from the company's IP.

As such, I have two separate load balancers pointing at it:

- internal.lb.example - an internal load balancer and
- lb.example - an external load balancer

The entry point to using the group is ***currently*** defined as two URLs:

- http://service.example.org
- http://internal.service.example.org

However, when the application is calling the service, it is passed the URL to talk to (of say, http://service.example.org) and doesn't have a concept of the fact that this potentially might not be the right URL to be calling from the environment it's in.

Is there a way either through Route53 or through other means to have a single URL that, dependant on which path is valid, will pass you on to the correct load balancer?

I'm aware that there's potentially a way to bypass the issue by connecting the office directly to the VPC (so you could just use an internal load balancer) but at least at the moment, this isn't a practical solution for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route53 recently added [private DNS](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/05/amazon-route-53-now-supports-private-dns-with-amazon-vpc/), which allows you to specify private DNS records that apply only within a VPC.

You can make two zones in Route53 for the same domain, set internal records up in one of them, and apply that in the VPC. Users outside the VPC would get the other zone.

Comment: Awesome! This is pretty much exactly what I was after! Thank you!

Comment: @Doug You're most welcome. :-)